# redux-form Cannot read property 'any' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

I have problem with `redux-from` in `react-native`. I want to implement a login form for my app. from tutorials around the web I wrote this code but have problem with this error

> Cannot read property 'any' of undefined
>
> [image: Error screenshot]

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-native": "0.53.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^5.3.2",
    "redux-persist": "^3.2.2"
  },
```

this is my **Login.js** component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";

class Login extends Component {
    onSignIn() {
        var { email, password } = this.props.fields;
        console.log(email.value, password.value);
    }

    render(){
        var {fields: {email, password}} = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.titleContainer} >
                    <Text style={styles.title} >ToDo</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.fields} >
                    <TextInput
                        {...email}
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={styles.TextInput}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.fields} >
                    <TextInput
                        {...password}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        style={styles.TextInput}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer} >
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.button} onPress={this.onSignIn} >
                            Signin
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.button}>
                            Signup
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
});

var validate = (formProps) => {
    var errors = {};

    return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
    fields: ['email', 'password'],
    validate: validate
}, null, null)(Login);
```

my reducer **index.js**

```
import update from "react-addons-update";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReduser } from "redux-form";

module.exports = combineReducers({
    form: formReduser
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that version of `redux-form` doesn't support react 16. Prop types have been moved to a separate package. Try upgrading `redux-form` to 5.3.6 or greater.